# Access data outside of Axios await get?

Tags: async-await, axios, nuxt.js

New to Axios, Vue, NuxtJS.

Most examples I've seen show either `.get` or `await`, but not both together. This code was pulled from several using Nuxt JS with headless CMS tutorials and is working, but now I can't seem to figure out how to access the data in other functions outside of the async call.

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
   async asyncData ({env, params}) {
      const {data} = await axios.get(`${env.cockpit.apiUrl}/collections/get/cat_ruleset?token=${env.cockpit.apiToken}&simple=1`);
      return {catrules:data}
    }
}
```

Comment: Call your asyncData method eg const result = asyncdata();  if you want it in nother import async data from location; and call it.

Answer (score 0):

```
export const addmore = async () => {

    const response = await axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1`);
    return response.data;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't appear that you've provided anything different than what I have above. How do I access the data outside of the async call?

Comment: according to my code you just need to call addmore() thats it